# Problems with automounting NFS on RHEL8

Tags: centos, rhel, nfs, automounting, autofs

I've run into some problems when configuring **autofs** on CentOS and I would really appreciate your help with it ^^

I have to VMs:

1. **CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003**, IP address: **10.110.163.10**

Two NFS shares defined in */etc/exports*:

```
/nfs-directory          *(rw,no_root_squash)
/additional-nfs         *(rw,no_root_squash)
```

2. **Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.2**

I'm trying to automount NFS from CentOS here

`showmount -e 10.110.163.10` gives me the following:

```
Export list for 10.110.163.10:
/additional-nfs *
/nfs-directory  *
```

I've installed *autofs*, created the configuration file */etc/auto.master.d/nfs-directory.autofs* and defined the following:

```
/nfs-directory          /etc/nfs-mount.auto
```

And in the file */etc/nfs-mount.auto* I defined:

```
*               -fstype=nfsv4,rw,sync           10.110.163.10:/nfs-directory/&
```

I enabled and restarted autofs, it does create the */nfs-directory*, but it's empty, I can't see any files inside it...

When I type `mount 10.110.163.10:/nfs-directory /mnt`, everything works fine, NFS mounts correctly and I can access file within the share, but I can't manage to do the same with the automounter.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your /etc/nfs-mount.auto  :

```
default              -rw,sync           10.110.163.10:/nfs-directory/
```

Per default the mount type is nfs ; also you can access the share with `/nfs-directory/default.`

You can enable logging on autofs in **/etc/autofs.conf** :

```
logging = debug
```

Check the logs : `journalctl -u autofs`
Restart autofs : `systemctl restart autofs`